# What is the maximum Summoner level in League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

I just wanted to know what the max level you can get your profile up to. I'm a new player and I have no idea what it is.

Answer (score 9):

<s>You can level up your profile to 30. Once you are 30, it unlocks ranked play where it tracks your ELO (a numeric skill level).</s>

As of [Patch 7.22](https://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch/patch-722-notes), League of Legends has uncapped leveling as per this [Preseason Update FAQ](https://support.riotgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/115012640908)

> What’s the new level cap?
>
> There’s no level cap! Level to infinity (but not beyond it—it's
>   dangerous to level beyond infinity).

Answer (score 7):

There is no max level in League of Legends. With the most recent update it has become possible to reach any level in the game.

Comment: Just to Clarify, this is valid since Patch 7.22 (Pre-Season 8, Week 1 )

Answer (score 4):

The maximum summoner level outside of a match is level 30.

The highest level for a champion during a match is level 18.

Answer (score 2):

The max level is 30 and then it becomes ranked.

Answer (score 1):

Since [patch 7.22](https://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch/patch-722-notes) League of Legends summoner levels are no longer capped so the maximum will be constantly changing. You can currently [see who has the highest summoner level here](https://lolnames.gg/en/highscores/). However the in game champion level is still capped at 18 normally, [an exception would be in URF games where champions can level up to 30](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ultra_Rapid_Fire).

Answer (score 0):

The maximum summoner level you can reach is level 30. At this point, you will allowed to play ranked matches. At level 20, you unlock tier 3 runes. The maximum level your champion can reach is 18.